# Django model choices from database, another model

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out how to allow for a model to take only certain values. But I can't use IntegerField with choices option because it's product database with couple thousand products. To be more precise- I'm trying to create app which manages product orders. For now my models are:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    komentarz = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    r = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    s = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    p = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
```

I created another app with product database, it contains around 3000 records.

```
class ProductBase(models.Model):
    r = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    s = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    p = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
```

Basically I want to allow Product model to take values inside database made thanks to ProductBase model. Any idea what should I use?

EDIT:
To make it more clear:

```
R S P 
Name 1 Parameter S Parameter P 
Name 2 Parameter S Parameter P 
Name 3 Parameter S Parameter P
```

This is ProductBase database. I want to allow Product to take only one of these three values. (in reality it's 3000)

Comment: Not sure if I get it. Do you want that Product model could take only values that exist in ProductBase model? Base on which field?

Comment: All of them actually. Not necessarily in divided state (r/s/p). The ProductBase looks like:
R              S                      P
Name 1    Parameter S    Parameter P
Name 2    Parameter S    Parameter P
Name 3    Parameter S    Parameter P
So for example I want to allow Product model to take one of these three ProductBase. EDIT: Main post edited so it's explained better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow only a specific set of values in Product model, base on some 'condition', I would just check this condition in the view function before saving a new Product object to the database. 
So if you get `r, s, p` to create new Product, let say from a form, then check whether the condition is met, then you save new Product object to db or not.

Let just say that set of r, s, p values must be exactly that same in Product and ProductBase. Example could be sth like that:

```
# receive data from the form
r_value = form.clean_data.get("r")
s_value = form.clean_data.get("s")
p_value = form.clean_data.get("p")

# Your condition
check_db = ProductBase.object.filter(
    s=s_value).filter(r=r_value).filter(p=p_value).exists()

if check_db:
    # create new product
    new_product = Product.object.create( #here goes values r, s, p )
    new_product.save()
else:
    # soma kind of feedback to user
```

The condition could be whatever you want, just change the logic.

Comment: That check will be usefull but what if I want to give user an option to choose from possible Products. I want it to look like a search engine, user can filter the ProductBase by parameter "r" for example, see what the matching records looks like and use "add" option on one of them- to add the ProductBase as on of Products in Order.

Comment: You can make a form that accepts r or s or p values and when a user submits the form, it could redirect him to the URL with listed all matching products. In the view there will be sth like ProductBase.object.filter(s= value provided by user ). You pass It to the context dictionary and loop content in HTML template. Each one with a button to add specific product with product.id as value. Then there will be no need for checking condition in the view.

Comment: Generally, one form to select the parameter and enter a value. Second with the list of options. To do it more dynamically it would require more tools than just Django. AJAX + JS for example.